# Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJU1O.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrfzp.png)

Hello, I am getting this error, can you help?

I made PHP version 8 but I got an error like this

My previous version is 7.x I don't remember exactly

Error details are available in the image

Required extensions installed

I am using the PHP file I shared below

```
<?php
  foreach($_GET    as $k => $v) $_GET[$k]    = strip_tags($v);
  foreach($_POST   as $k => $v) $_POST[$k]   = strip_tags($v);


  if($_POST){
    include 'panel/fonksiyon.php';

    if($_POST['islem'] == 'urun-ekle'){
        if(is_numeric($_POST['urun_id']) AND is_numeric($_POST['adet']) AND is_numeric($_POST['secenek_id'])){
            if($_POST['adet'] < 1){
              $_POST['adet'] = 1;
            }
            $urunquery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun where id=:id LIMIT 1");
            $urun = $urunquery->execute(array(":id"=>$_POST['urun_id']));
            $urun = $urunquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($urun){
              if($_POST['secenek_id'] > 0){
                $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_secenek_alt where id=:id LIMIT 1");
                $alt_secenek = $query->execute(array(":id"=>$_POST['secenek_id']));
                $alt_secenek = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($alt_secenek){
                  if($_POST['adet'] > $alt_secenek['stok']){
                    echo 0;
                  }else{
                    $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'].'-'.$_POST['secenek_id'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['urun_id'][$uniqid]      = $_POST['urun_id'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['adet'][$uniqid]         = $_POST['adet'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['secenek_id'][$uniqid]   = $_POST['secenek_id'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['key'][$uniqid]          = $uniqid;
                    echo 2;
                  }
                }else{
                  echo 1;
                }
              }else{
                  if($_POST['adet'] > $urun['stok']){
                    echo 0;
                  }else{
                    $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['urun_id'][$uniqid]      = $_POST['urun_id'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['adet'][$uniqid]         = $_POST['adet'];
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['secenek_id'][$uniqid]   = 0;
                    $_SESSION['sepet']['key'][$uniqid]          = $uniqid;
                    echo 2;
                  }
              }
            }else{
              echo 1;
            }
        }else{
          echo 1;
        }
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'listele'){
      echo '<div class="sepet_baslik">Sepetim <span>('.count($_SESSION['sepet']['key']).' Ürün)</span> <i class="las la-times" data-sepet-kapat=""></i></div><ul class="sepet_urunler secimli">';
      if(count($_SESSION['sepet']['key']) > 0){
        $toplam = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['sepet']['key'] as $key) {

          $urunquery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun where id=:id LIMIT 1");
          $urun = $urunquery->execute(array(":id"=>$_SESSION['sepet']['urun_id'][$key]));
          $urun = $urunquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          $urunimg = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_img where urun_id=:urun_id LIMIT 1");
          $uimg = $urunimg->execute(array(":urun_id"=>$_SESSION['sepet']['urun_id'][$key]));
          $uimg = $urunimg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          $secenek = '';

          $alt_secenek_fiyat = 0;
          if($_SESSION['sepet']['secenek_id'][$key] !=0){
            $alt_secenek = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_secenek_alt where id=:id LIMIT 1");
                    $as = $alt_secenek->execute(array(":id"=>$_SESSION['sepet']['secenek_id'][$key]));
                    $as = $alt_secenek->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $ust_secenek = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM urun_secenek where id=:id LIMIT 1");
                    $us = $ust_secenek->execute(array(":id"=>$as['urun_secenek_id']));
                    $us = $ust_secenek->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $alt_secenek_fiyat = $as['fiyat'];

                    $secenek = '<div><span>'.$us['baslik'].':</span> <span>'.$as['baslik'].'</span></div>';
          }

          echo '<li>
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4"><a href="urun/'.$urun['sef'].'"><img src="upload/'.$uimg['img'].'" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8">
                    <a href="urun/'.$urun['sef'].'">'.$urun['baslik'].'</a>
                    '.$secenek.'
                    <div><span>Adet:</span> <span>'.$_SESSION['sepet']['adet'][$key].' Adet</span></div>
                    <div><span>Fiyat:</span> <span>'.fiyat($urun['fiyat'] + $alt_secenek_fiyat).' TL</span></div>
                    <div data-sepet-sil="'.$key.'"><i class="las la-trash"></i></div>
                  </div>
              </li>';

          $toplam += $_SESSION['sepet']['adet'][$key] * ($urun['fiyat'] + $alt_secenek_fiyat);
        }

        echo '</ul><div class="sepet_alt">
              <div class="toplam_tutar"><span>Toplam Tutar:</span> <span>'.fiyat($toplam).' TL</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-10 mt-10"><a href="sepetim" class="btn icon-btn btn-success  mt-10"><i class="las la-shopping-cart"></i> Sepetime Git</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-12"><a href="index.php" class="btn icon-btn btn-warning"><i class="las la-user-lock"></i> Alışverişe Devam Et</a></div>
            </div>';
      }else{
        echo '<li class="sepet_bos"><p>Sepetinizde Ürün Bulunmuyor.</p></li>';
      }
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'sepet_sil'){
        $uniqid = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_SESSION['sepet']['urun_id'][$uniqid]);
        unset($_SESSION['sepet']['adet'][$uniqid]);
        unset($_SESSION['sepet']['secenek_id'][$uniqid]);
        unset($_SESSION['sepet']['key'][$uniqid]);
        echo 1;
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'sepet_sayisi'){
        echo @count($_SESSION['sepet']['key']);
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'favori-ekle'){

      $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'];
      $_SESSION['favori']['urun_id'][$uniqid]      = $_POST['urun_id'];;
      $_SESSION['favori']['key'][$uniqid]          = $uniqid;
      echo 1;
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'favori-sil'){
        $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'];
        unset($_SESSION['favori']['urun_id'][$uniqid]);
        unset($_SESSION['favori']['key'][$uniqid]);
        echo 1;
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'karsilastir-ekle'){

      $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'];
      $_SESSION['karsilastir']['urun_id'][$uniqid]      = $_POST['urun_id'];;
      $_SESSION['karsilastir']['key'][$uniqid]          = $uniqid;
      echo 1;
    }else if($_POST['islem'] == 'karsilastir-sil'){
        $uniqid = $_POST['urun_id'];
        unset($_SESSION['karsilastir']['urun_id'][$uniqid]);
        unset($_SESSION['karsilastir']['key'][$uniqid]);
        echo 1;
    }

  }


?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is causing this error please?

Comment: Also, please can you put the error message as text in your question (not an image) - that helps to make it easier to read and searchable for other people with a similar problem

Comment: I detailed more

Comment: Which is line 55 please?

Comment: echo '<div class="sepet_baslik">Sepetim <span>('.count($_SESSION['sepet']['key']).' Ürün)</span> <i class="las la-times" data-sepet-kapat=""></i></div><ul class="sepet_urunler secimli">';

Comment: The warnings above your error are the reason why this is happening, solve the warnings, and the error will also be solved.

Comment: I tried to clear the warnings but unfortunately without success

Comment: The error message indicates that at the point this code is run, the session variable `$_SESSION['sepet']` is not set.  You therefore can't access (or count) sub elements of it, because it doesn't have a value.  I suggest re-examining the logic or your code to understand where this value should be set

Comment: This add to cart function, ironically, throws an error like this when the cart is empty. When I add any product, it works normally, when I delete the added product, it works normally.However, when I look at the cart without adding products to the cart, it gives such an error.

Comment: That indicates that you are never properly initializing `$_SESSION['sepet']` anywhere then. When you add a product, it appears to get created as an array automatically at this point, and when you remove products from that array again, it still _stays_ an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the error code as text in your question, and not as an image link (links go stale!).